# Can notification created by notify-send in linux closed by user's operation?

Tags: linux

I want to use notify-send to remind me of something important.When I test it,it just shows a few seconds.I check the usage of notify-send and it has -t flag to specify the timeout.
But I want to close the notification manually,make sure I will not miss the notification,is there a way to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Oh,I have found `notify-send -t 0` which will prompt a message box ,but it change the UI completely...